# Not able to configure Route53 record for hosting static website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I want to host static website which looks very straight forward as per AWS documentation like creating two buckets example.com and www.example.com etc.

but while configuring on Route 53; and creating Alias A record; it is not populating that S3 bucket name.. I even tried to put value manually it says

> "Alias Target contains an invalid value"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was that on S3 bucket level --> Add permissions --> Let Everyone List the contents. I think instead of Everyone even "Authenticated AWS User" should work fine.

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  There's no such requirement.  More likely, this was a replication delay if the bucket was new and it started working only by coincidence.

Comment: @Michael .. I  really spent days to figure it out.. trust me that only helped; because otherwise permissions on that bucket were ONLY for myself.. And as the solution is not typical documented; I had posted here on stackoverflow

Comment: I have numerous web site hosting buckets with Route 53 and none of them are configured this way.  There's no reason why you should have to allow *anyone* to list your bucket's contents (!?) in order to be able to create a DNS alias.  I wouldn't want someone who doesn't understand the implications of this advice to follow it.  We really need to understand the mechanisms involved, here.

Answer (score 0):

As at the time of writing, based on my experience, there are 3 things that you need to do:

1. use the **new** Route53 console. The S3 bucket will not be listed if you are using the **old** Route 53 console. You will need to use the **new** Route 53 console. As to how to switch between the two, in the top section of the route 53 dashboard it will asks you whether you want to switch between the old/new console. If it is not there, then you will need to contact AWS
2. make sure that your buckets are configured to be publicly accessible, both in **Bucket policy** and in **Block public access** permission setting
3. make sure your **bucket name** is the same as your subdomain.

Example 1: if I want to make an A record with blog.mycoolwebsite.com then the bucket name need to be blog.mycoolwebsite.com.

Example 2: if I want to make an A record in the root domain mycoolwebsite.com then the bucket name need to be mycoolwebsite.com